# argument "no" is missing with no default

Tags: r, if-statement

I am trying to run an ifelse statement using the following code. I have "No Lic" specified as the no statement, but I am still getting the "argument "no" is missing with no default" and can't figure out why.

Data:

```
ELED<-data.frame("ID"=1:6,"UG_Degree_Term"= c(201809,201901,201906,201909,202001,202006),"Test_Date"=c('2019-02-27','2018-10-23','2019-07-09','2019-01-18','2019-04-23','2018-7-12'))
ELED$Test_Date<-anytime(ELED$Test_Date)
```

Code:

```
ELED$UVM_Lic_Rec<-with(ELED,
           ifelse(UG_Degree_Term==201809 & Test_Date<=as.POSIXct('2019-12-31'),"2019"),
           ifelse(UG_Degree_Term==201901 & Test_Date<=as.POSIXct('2020-05-30'),"2019"),
           ifelse(UG_Degree_Term==201906 & Test_Date<=as.POSIXct('2020-08-31'),"2019"),
           ifelse(UG_Degree_Term==201909 & Test_Date<=as.POSIXct('2020-12-31'),"2020"),
           ifelse(UG_Degree_Term==202001 & Test_Date<=as.POSIXct('2021-05-30'),"2020"),
           ifelse(UG_Degree_Term==202006 & Test_Date<=as.POSIXct('2021-08-31'),"2020",'No Lic'))
```

Comment: Since you're running a lot of `ifelse()` statements, it may be better to create a reference table and do a join.

Comment: asimpfen, welcome to stackoverflow (I'm pretty new myself!). If you think the answer I wrote solved your problem, please consider designating it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ifelse` function generally requires three arguments:

- `test`: the condition,
- `yes`: what to return if the condition holds,
- `no`: what to return if the condition does not hold.

You are missing the third one (the `no` argument), and R's error message is saying that (admittedly in an opaque way).

Here I reproduce the error with a simpler example:

```
> x <- 1
> ifelse(x == 1, "YES")
[1] "YES"
> ifelse(x == 0, "YES")
Error in ifelse(x == 0, "YES") : 
  argument "no" is missing, with no default
> ifelse(x == 0, "YES", "NO")
[1] "NO"
```

The problem with your code is that the closing parentheses for each `ifelse` statement appears directly after the `yes` argument. They need to go at the end, like this:

```
ELED$UVM_Lic_Rec<-with(ELED,
       ifelse(UG_Degree_Term==201809 & Test_Date<=as.POSIXct('2019-12-31'),"2019",
       ifelse(UG_Degree_Term==201901 & Test_Date<=as.POSIXct('2020-05-30'),"2019",
       ifelse(UG_Degree_Term==201906 & Test_Date<=as.POSIXct('2020-08-31'),"2019",
       ifelse(UG_Degree_Term==201909 & Test_Date<=as.POSIXct('2020-12-31'),"2020",
       ifelse(UG_Degree_Term==202001 & Test_Date<=as.POSIXct('2021-05-30'),"2020",
       ifelse(UG_Degree_Term==202006 & Test_Date<=as.POSIXct('2021-08-31'),"2020",'No Lic')))))))
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is the final "No Lic" not a no statement? If not how do I make it a no statement?

Comment: You shouldn't get an error for the last line of code, because you provide both a `yes` and a `no` argument. For the others you will get the error you specified if the condition is not met for at least one row.

Comment: I thought with nested ifelse statements, like the below example. The no statement only came in the very last statement, not in every statement. df$Status <- ifelse(df$ProcessDate < as.POSIXct('2011-12-29 14:48:00'), 
                    'Before', 
                    ifelse(df$ProcessDate < as.POSIXct('2011-12-29 15:16:00'), 
                           'Between', 
                           'After'))

Comment: OK hold on I was wrong. I didn't catch that these were nested statements. Sorry. I can't see why your code is failing (though I agree with the commenter that this code is hard to read). It would help if you provided a MWE including some data.

Comment: Okay, I cleaned up the code and added an example of the data I'm working with.

Comment: The issue with your code is the closing parentheses. I have edited my answer to include this point.